# Quick item removal from LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have the following linked list:

```
LinkedList<Segment> myList = new LinkedList<Segment>();
```

Why when I do:

```
myList.Remove(new Segment(4,8));
```

the following `Segment.Equals()` method is called:

```
class Segment
{
   ...

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {                         
      return Equals((Segment)obj);
   }

}
```

instead of this one:

```
class Segment
{
   ...

   public bool Equals(Segment other)
   {                        
      return other.V1 == V1 && other.V2 == V2;
   }     
}
```

Isn't there any way to skip `object` boxing and unboxing and use the latter - more fast - approach?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the link between IndexLine and Segment? Is IndexLine a base abstract class?

Comment: Maybe it's too early in the morning for me, but `Segment` is a reference type - where is the boxing occurring?

Comment: Could it be it's because its an "override-issue" instead of a "boxing-issue"?

Comment: @ken2k: Sorry, while simplifying my code I forgot to rename it.

Comment: The "object" version is called because `Segment` does not implement `IEquatable<Segment>`. In any case, as Graham Clark says there is no boxing here because `Segment` is a `class`, not a `struct`. Don't confuse static typing as `object` with boxing.

Comment: @Graham: You can be right, but one method call could be saved.

Comment: did you implement `IEquatable<T>`? did you override `.GetHashCode`?

Comment: @Jon it's called "casting" :)

Comment: If removal of an element by its value is critical then you probably shouldn't be using a LinkedList in the first place.

Comment: @Henk: What do you recommend?

Comment: What are your requirements and constraints?

Comment: AddFirst(T), AddLast(T), RemoveFirst(T), and very fast Remove(T)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your element type to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
class Segment : IEquatable<Segment>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals(Segment other)
    {                        
        return 
            (object)other != null &&
            other.V1 == V1 && 
            other.V2 == V2;
    }     
}
```

Comment: are you sure, that you are not running into a stackoverflow? rather use `.ReferenceEquals` for checking against null!

Comment: The equality and inequality operators (`==` and `!=`) always perform reference equality checks, unless the said operators are explicitly overridden by the implemented class (as in the case of `string`). You can refer to the MSDN example for [`IEquatable<T>.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx), which also uses `other == null`.

Comment: I know, I just think that it is way clearer to explicitely use `.ReferenceEquals`. If someone implements his/her own `.Equals`, the possibility of overriding the equality-operator is *very* high. Otherwise an `IEqualityComparer<T>` (if applicable) should be used.

Comment: btw, your msdn-entry (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) really *sucks*, when it comes to design ... who, in gods name, implements the equality-chain in such a complicated way?!

Comment: Fair enough, although it is considered bad practice to override `==` whenever one overrides `Equals` – the former should *only* ever be overridden for immutable types. I've introduced a type-cast to `object` to ensure reference equality.

Comment: And I agree about the poor implementation of the MSDN example. A `return true else return false` indicates that the implementor does not really understand booleans.

Comment: I'm not too much into this topic, but... is there any `.Find` or other equality-checking-method (to do some replacing/removing/adding) in the framework-classes, which uses `==` instead of `.Equals`? This might be a *pitfall* otherwise ... I never needed to override `==` or `!=` on mutable types when I've used them in collections, but I am just saying that the possibility is high. (You never know if you have to deal with the implementor of the msdn-entry, though)

Comment: The `return`-clauses are the cherry on top :)

Comment: I'm not aware of any .NET classes relying on the equality operators for equality checking. The new collection classes document their behaviour explicitly; for example, in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`: “You can specify an implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic equality comparer `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is used. If type `TKey` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.”

Comment: just for anyone who's interested: I've took the long road to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` some time ago: http://pastebin.com/mWmJW5v5

Comment: and ... your last comment was, once again, an awesome clarification - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList<T>.Remove` uses `LinkedList<T>.Find` to find the element to remove, and `LinkedList<T>.Find` uses the [default equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) to perform the comparison, which in your case is the equality comparer based on `Object.Equals`.

From MSDN:

> The **Default** property checks whether type *T* implements the [System.IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface and, if so, returns an [EqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an [EqualityComparer<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) that uses the overrides of [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) and [Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) provided by *T*.

By implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface you can provide your own implementation of equality which will then be used by `LinkedList<T>`.